# Foundation 6, dropdown menu box size

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I created a top-bar menu using Foundation 6 looking at its documentation and some tutorials on its page. I managed to make it work responsively, changes from dropdown to drilldown when in mobile view. All ok, but I'm missing something here. The dropdown boxes don't expand to make menu options one line each. The Foundation class "is-dropdown-submenu" set a min-width of 200px. But that doesn't work as a minimum width. It works as the max-width because dropdown boxes doesn't expand beyond that value. I have to manually set a larger width to place all my menu options in one line each. Is there any way to dropdown boxes adjust its size automatically?
Any ideas?

```
<div class="top-bar">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="top-bar-title">
                <span data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
                    <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
                </span>
                <img class="logo" src="https://placehold.it/145x40&text=LOGO">
            </div>
            <div id="responsive-menu">
                <div class="top-bar-left">
                    <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu navigation" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown" 
                    data-back-button='<li class="js-drilldown-back"><a tabindex="0">Return</a></li>'>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
                            <ul class="vertical menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Lorem</a>
                            <ul class="vertical menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Ipsum</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/evedRp)

Comment: Thanks for the codepen.

Comment: Please clarify.  You do not like the wrapping?  Screenshot - https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ahq5gJGSap8yge013ze00lz5JnZY8w

Comment: On very small screens, that kind of wrapping could be acceptable (but in reality that menu would have changed to mobile format). Like I said in my question, F6 have this ".is-dropdown-submenu" CSS class with a default value of 200px. Try changing that value on my codepen or completely removing that class to see what I'm talking. What I would want is for that width size to grow accordingly to my menu text item. Unfortunately F6 documentation is never clear enough about all options and currently I don't have a choice to change to another framework :/

Comment: So you want the text to scale to fit?